# Problems using a Wiki to HTML script (FFNN) as Helper in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, wiki

I've found this [script](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/projects/wiki-text-to-html.php) for converting wiki syntax to HTML in php and i've tried to integrate it into **Codeigniter**. it seems really easy to use. However, it's not working, and instead producing around 8 of these errors:

```
Message: Use of undefined constant LS_NONE - assumed 'LS_NONE'
```

I think this is because Codeigniter helpers are not a class but rather functions, and this bit of code is a class, or does this issue lie with something else? I've also tried to use it as a model without success.

It also seems horribly outdated (2007). Could somebody suggest a really simple alternative or maybe give an idea of how to convert this to a simple function if that is possible? It's a very short piece of code. I'm not sure how these constants work in relationship to a function versus a class.

I've given the Text_Wiki from Pear ago, but the use and complexity well exceeds both my requirements and knowledge :)

//Any help would be greatly appreciated

Loaded using:

```
    $row = $query->row();
    $content=$row->course_content;
    $this->load->helper('wiki');
    $content=explode("\n", $content);               
    $output = WikiTextToHTML::convertWikiTextToHTML($content);
    $html=array_merge($output);
    $data['contents'][]= $html;
    $this->load->view('default/a',$data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the script is actually a class. put it in the libraries folder and load it with `$this->load->library()`. That will allow it to properly initialize and define the constants that it uses.

something like:

```
$this->load->library('wikitexttohtml');
$this->wikitexttohtml->convertWikiTextToHTML($wiki_text);
```

Comment: that would of course be the most appropriate place to put it. thank you :)